# How did mundus come to mean both world and clean?

Tags: etymology, vocabulary, meaning

Basically what's in the title: How did ***mundus*** come to mean both [*world*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dmundus2) and [*clean*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dmundus1)? L&S lists a number of other meanings, but in my knowledge these are two very frequent uses, that do not seem to have much in common.

I have always wondered whether there is any documented history to explain such different meanings. Was it just the fruit of convergent evolution, a complex process of meaning change from a common original meaning, or something different? I find it even funny that with time in Ecclesiastical Latin both meanings came to be close to opposite: the World as *the realm of sin and death*, and cleanliness as the absense of evil.

---

My research so far:

There is a [Proto-IE root](http://starling.rinet.ru/cgi-bin/response.cgi?root=config&morpho=0&basename=%5Cdata%5Cie%5Cpiet&first=1&off=&text_lat=mundus&method_lat=substring&ic_lat=on&sort=proto&ic_any=on) related to mundus meaning to adorn, which would explain most of the *clean* meaning, but I have not found anything for the *world* part.

Latin also has the words *Terra* and *Universum*.

[*Terra*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dterra) means Earth (as a *part* of the whole world, as I understand from the first quote to Cicero in L&S, which makes sense to me). It also has a close [PIE root](http://starling.rinet.ru/cgi-bin/response.cgi?root=config&morpho=0&basename=%5Cdata%5Cie%5Cpiet&first=1&off=&text_proto=&method_proto=substring&ic_proto=on&text_meaning=&method_meaning=substring&ic_meaning=on&text_hitt=&method_hitt=substring&ic_hitt=on&text_tokh=&method_tokh=substring&ic_tokh=on&text_ind=&method_ind=substring&ic_ind=on&text_avest=&method_avest=substring&ic_avest=on&text_iran=&method_iran=substring&ic_iran=on&text_arm=&method_arm=substring&ic_arm=on&text_greek=&method_greek=substring&ic_greek=on&text_slav=&method_slav=substring&ic_slav=on&text_balt=&method_balt=substring&ic_balt=on&text_germ=&method_germ=substring&ic_germ=on&text_lat=terra&method_lat=substring&ic_lat=on&text_ital=&method_ital=substring&ic_ital=on&text_celt=&method_celt=substring&ic_celt=on&text_alb=&method_alb=substring&ic_alb=on&text_rusmean=&method_rusmean=substring&ic_rusmean=on&text_refer=&method_refer=substring&ic_refer=on&text_comment=&method_comment=substring&ic_comment=on&text_any=&method_any=substring&sort=proto&ic_any=on) with the same meaning. That seems to suggest *terra* predates *mundus*.

About *universum* I do not have so many clues, except that it seems to be a composite of uni+versus, the later having some ancient semantic field related to [*turning*](http://starling.rinet.ru/cgi-bin/response.cgi?root=config&morpho=0&basename=%5Cdata%5Cie%5Cpiet&first=1&off=&text_proto=&method_proto=substring&ic_proto=on&text_meaning=&method_meaning=substring&ic_meaning=on&text_hitt=&method_hitt=substring&ic_hitt=on&text_tokh=&method_tokh=substring&ic_tokh=on&text_ind=&method_ind=substring&ic_ind=on&text_avest=&method_avest=substring&ic_avest=on&text_iran=&method_iran=substring&ic_iran=on&text_arm=&method_arm=substring&ic_arm=on&text_greek=&method_greek=substring&ic_greek=on&text_slav=&method_slav=substring&ic_slav=on&text_balt=&method_balt=substring&ic_balt=on&text_germ=&method_germ=substring&ic_germ=on&text_lat=versu&method_lat=substring&ic_lat=on&text_ital=&method_ital=substring&ic_ital=on&text_celt=&method_celt=substring&ic_celt=on&text_alb=&method_alb=substring&ic_alb=on&text_rusmean=&method_rusmean=substring&ic_rusmean=on&text_refer=&method_refer=substring&ic_refer=on&text_comment=&method_comment=substring&ic_comment=on&text_any=&method_any=substring&sort=proto&ic_any=on).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's possible that the identity is a coincidence and that the adjective and the noun are unrelated homophones. De Vaan's etymological dictionary lists the two words as separate entries and does not draw any connection between them.

That said, it seems plausible that there is a relationship, namely that the "world" sense is based on a calque of the Greek word κόσμος. This has the basic meaning of "order", but also means both "ornament, decoration" and "world", just like the noun *mundus*. (The semantic connection appears to be the idea of the world as a "natural order".) The concepts "clean" and "ornament" are semantically close enough that *mundus* (adj.) and *mundus* (n.) could easily be related, and then the latter would have picked up its additional meaning of "world" in imitation of the Greek word. The possibility of Greek influence is supported by the fact that *mundus* appears to have been a specifically philosophical word for "world", as opposed to a more common term like *orbis terrarum*. (ETA: as fdb points out, there's a difference in meaning between *mundus* and *orbis terrarum*: the former, like Greek κόσμος, means "the universe", while the latter means "the Earth".)

Answer (score 4):

Came across this post wondering about Italian word "immondizia" meaning "garbage" with origin from Latin "im" ("without") + "mundus" ("clean" or "elegant").

"Mundus" reminded me of Lithuanian "mandagus" ("polite"). Of course, being polite is nice and elegant and worldly. If you add the prefix "ne" (meaning "not", similar to "without") you get "nemandagus", or "impolite".  Garbage is certainly impolite!

Comment: Good point; also, in Italian there is the adjective _immondo_ (from which I'm sure _immondizia_ comes) to describe something as very very dirty.

Answer (score 4):

The original Latin word for ‘world’ was *orbs*.
*Mundus* is a late translation for the Greek word *kosmos*. This Greek word conveys the idea of order, and order from a Greek point of view means the right measure, symmetry, harmony and beauty. It was so because the world or the universe was thought in Greece to be that way: orderly constructed, harmonious and beautiful. *Mundus* is something clean and tidy.

It doesn’t offer all the possible meanings which the greek *kosmos* does, but it was the best translation the Latin language could make.

Comment: *Mundus* in the sense of 'world' is attested as early as Plautus. It's *possible* it was influenced by the Greek κόσμος, but not at all certain (especially since *mundus* also means 'subterranean vault', a meaning it could not have taken from the Greek).